# How to determine http vs https in nodejs / nextjs api handler

Tags: node.js, http-headers, next.js

In order to properly build my urls in my xml sitemaps and rss feeds I want to determine if the webpage is currently served over http or https, so it also works locally in development.

```js
export default function handler(req, res) {
  const host = req.headers.host;
  const proto = req.connection.encrypted ? "https" : "http";

  //construct url for xml sitemaps
}
```

With above code however also on Vercel it still shows as being served over `http`. I would expect it to run as `https`. Is there a better way to figure out `http` vs `https`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Next.js api routes run behind a proxy which is offloading to http the protocol is `http`.

By changing the code to the following I was able to first check at what protocol the proxy runs.

```js
  const proto = req.headers["x-forwarded-proto"];
```

However this will break the thing in development where you are not running behind a proxy, or a different way of deploying the solution that might also not involve a proxy. To support both use cases I eventually ended up with the following code.

```js
  const proto =
    req.headers["x-forwarded-proto"] || req.connection.encrypted
      ? "https"
      : "http";
```

Whenever the `x-forwarded-proto` header is not present (`undefined`) we fall back to req.connection.encrypted to determine if we should serve on `http` vs `https`.

Now it works on localhost as well a Vercel deployment.

Comment: req.connection is deprecated. It says to use req.socket instead, but I am not seeing an encrypted param.

Comment: Same issue, were you able to resolve this?

Comment: The official recommendation is to use the strategy above, and otherwise assume `http`. See this issue from next.js: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/2469

Answer (score 2):

my solution:

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps  = async (context: any) => {
    // Fetch data from external API
    const reqUrl = context.req.headers["referer"];
    const url = new URL(reqUrl);

    console.log('====================================');
    console.log(url.protocol); // http
    console.log('====================================');

    // const res = await fetch(`${origin}/api/projets`)
    // const data = await res.json()
  
    // Pass data to the page via props
    return { props: { data } }
}
```